# c++ getline into array, separated by new line

Tags: c++, arrays, getline

Basicly I have a text file with numbers separated by new lines. I want to input each number in to an array, and when a new line comes with a new number, that new number should be inserted into the next slot in the array

Comment: And what is the question?

Answer (score 1):

So the file is like:

```
10
20
36
```

to read this in something like this will work:

```
std::ifstream file {"file_name"};
int t;
std::vector<int> nums;
while(file >> t) 
   numes.push_back(t);
```

Or if you are comfortable with the std lib:

```
std::ifstream file {"file_name"};
std::vector<int> nums {
  std::istream_iterator<int> { file },
  std::istream_iterator<int> {      }
};
```

After that the following:

```
for(int n : nums) 
    std::cout << n ", ";
```

Will print

```
10, 20, 36,
```

to stdout.

Comment: for (int n : nums)
std::cout << n ", ";
Doesn't seem to work, error in the conditions for the loop, i haven't used vectors befor so I don't know whats wrong

Comment: @user1205116 sorry my mistake, `for (int n : nums) std::cout << n << ", ";`

Comment: @user1205116 also note: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector